# Javascript executes correctly with break point, but not without break point - why?

Tags: javascript

I have a strange JavaScript issue: when I run my JavaScript with a breakpoint (Firebug) on the line with window.location..., my function works correctly. But when I take the breakpoint away, it doesn't work any more. It behaves as if it didn't execute the savePublication() function any more.

Has someone ever seen such a problem? Here is my code

```
$("#add").click(function (e) {

    // Create array with id values of checked checkboxes
    var idarray = $( "input:checked" )
         .map(function() { return $(this).attr("class"); }) //Project classes
         .get(); //to Array


    // save each checked publication to database    
    $.each(idarray, function(index, value) {
        savePublication(value);
    });

    // load new window
    var uid = $( '[name="user_id"]' ).val();
    window.location.href = BASE + '/cv/' + uid+'?panel=accordion_8';

});
```

In cas this is important to solve the problem, here is the function savePublication() to:

```
function savePublication(c) {

    // set variables
    var author;
    var title;
    var year;
    var subtitle;
    var user_id = $( '[name="user_id"]' ).val();


    // for each element with class = c
    $("."+c).each(function() {
        // get element name
        var attribute = $(this).attr("name");

        // get values of attributes and set new variables with values
        if(attribute === "author") author = htmlspecialchars_decode($(this).text());
        if(attribute === "contributor") contributor = $(this).text();
        if(attribute === "title") title = $(this).text();
        if(attribute === "year") year = $(this).text();
    });

    // variable joining authors and contributors
    var authors = author + ", " + contributor;

    // store data using appropriate route
    $.post(BASE + '/publication/storeWorldCat',
              {
                authors:    authors,
                title:      title,
                subtitle:   "à corriger dans addWorldCat.js",
                year:       year,
                user_id:    user_id,
              },
    function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try using a `setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);` to let the ajax complete its request

Comment: It might be a timing problem. Some element might not exist, but because of the break point the script blocks long enough.

Comment: @ReeceJHayward worst soluition ever! hahaha

Comment: why? your controller clearly isn't completing its operation in time. alternatively, you could call your controller non-asynchronously

Comment: Hmmm... it passes over it right away. It goes so fast, I can't imagine that there was a timeout. Any idea why?

Comment: how can I call my controller non-asynchonousely? That's a good idea!!!

Comment: see my answer below for how to call your controller non-asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

Once you go to another page JavaScript stops executing.
Your `$.post` should have happened but the success may or may not execute depending on how long the `$.post` takes.

When you place a breakpoint, the $.post finishes and the success callback is executed.

You can work around this by either setting `async: false` or by waiting on the $.post:

```
$.post(BASE + '/publication/storeWorldCat',
          {
            authors:    authors,
            title:      title,
            subtitle:   "à corriger dans addWorldCat.js",
            year:       year,
            user_id:    user_id,
          },
function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
}).done(function() { 
     window.location = "...";
});
```

See here for more information on [$.post().done()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

You could call your controller synchronously like so:

```
var data = {
            authors:    authors,
            title:      title,
            subtitle:   "à corriger dans addWorldCat.js",
            year:       year,
            user_id:    user_id,
};

var success = function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: BASE + '/publication/storeWorldCat',
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false
});
```